# Duplicate headers when inluding a filter in security webflux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

im having an issue,I am developing a security application that functions as a gateway. It uses WebFlux Security and sends requests to a REST API, which acts as a resource server (OAuth2). The problem lies in that I inject a filter which collects a token and then sends it through the headers so that this token can reach the resource server. The issue is that when logging the headers at the resource server, it shows that the headers come duplicated. Attached is the filter:

````
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {

    return exchange.getPrincipal()
            .filter(principal -> principal instanceof Authentication)
            .map(Authentication.class::cast)
            .doOnNext(authentication -> {
                if (authentication != null) {
                    String tokenDetails = TokenUtils.extractTokenDetails(authentication);
                    // Añadir el token a los encabezados de la solicitud saliente
                    ServerHttpRequest mutatedRequest = exchange.getRequest()
                            .mutate()
                            .header("superToken", tokenDetails)
                            .build();
                    exchange.mutate().request(mutatedRequest);
                }
            })
            .then(chain.filter(exchange));

} ```
````

and these are the logs from the resource server:

````
Header:  upgrade-insecure-requests1
Header:  user-agentMozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Header:  accepttext/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Header:  sec-fetch-sitecross-site
Header:  sec-fetch-modenavigate
Header:  sec-fetch-user?1
Header:  sec-fetch-destdocument
Header:  sec-ch-ua"Not A(Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="121", "Chromium";v="121"
Header:  sec-ch-ua-mobile?0
Header:  sec-ch-ua-platform"Windows"
Header:  accept-encodinggzip, deflate, br
Header:  accept-languagees-ES,es;q=0.9
Header:  supertokeneyJraWQiOiI4ZTA5ODhmMC1iMjg4LTExZWUtODYyZi0zN2EwYTRmY2RjM2IiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.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.AJ9nIRT4hkAv3zMJ6QxbWHKbfbtZ358jTrbp1BDLs0A9ih2QCVsro7znwvD9Uu8LBs391ttt_d8TPo-eVY0W9k292F2LxxSBLE85CMh19yfa_Zp9k0bsoH8bDHkEIE5dexskBhESp9i2wOlBqN3bPtRvaGGwxR5TwWFri_8QMy83ysaLeU8a-kfPnKtiCrMrRdMf8j4GO6NENwDJ9omlXfazXpdh4yptltyv1U3Ho7dlRp-ioGtG9sLCk_JNNR9r51Ly5tyTLbRtAlB48-Gzv9x06iiJBKGZIG95H2oYSsRROo34TN3I42uzUHwskuivem1eI8C41Q0JybHb0_-mNQ
Header:  traceidb9dd7183-a0e1-4543-b96e-cb9db484f090
Header:  authorizationBearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImRlZmF1bHQifQ.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.DzgajPezQeJEW0g1qSZdBc8VR8OgQNZ1uVgNYs3iCABYYOThlDbqt5vK6TvcNkOzqnA8kxzG4z8iD0EDBTnbP34-ZFmQpIVDjpYaMsuewrTza9o7HVlPMyRDtpUthtr2HWzW_m72sGy2ylugV35OdONGAtHzYjEXpCqEtwc3_zGZSp79rkHWYfffHEvUzmKmj3ysEoQXr9593EbMMk45Z-qrxydBwKDAibsICDLDkgBRPJ0uiOr8osVQCgrEoLq8xRKCn3U3_vXMqjq8fmA_QabGrUA1TDowFjmjIjNQy-5l0atwkBYtu7vVsyD2dvbLWQVQdjyMcPTL4NdTKEg8aA
Header:  forwardedproto=http;host="localhost:8090";for="[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:51180"
Header:  x-forwarded-for0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
Header:  x-forwarded-protohttp
Header:  x-forwarded-port8090
Header:  x-forwarded-hostlocalhost:8090
Header:  hostlocalhost:8080
Header:  content-length0
Header:  cache-controlmax-age=0
Header:  upgrade-insecure-requests1
Header:  user-agentMozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Header:  accepttext/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Header:  sec-fetch-sitecross-site
Header:  sec-fetch-modenavigate
Header:  sec-fetch-user?1
Header:  sec-fetch-destdocument
Header:  sec-ch-ua"Not A(Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="121", "Chromium";v="121"
Header:  sec-ch-ua-mobile?0
Header:  sec-ch-ua-platform"Windows"
Header:  accept-encodinggzip, deflate, br
Header:  accept-languagees-ES,es;q=0.9
Header:  supertokeneyJraWQiOiI4ZTA5ODhmMC1iMjg4LTExZWUtODYyZi0zN2EwYTRmY2RjM2IiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.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.AJ9nIRT4hkAv3zMJ6QxbWHKbfbtZ358jTrbp1BDLs0A9ih2QCVsro7znwvD9Uu8LBs391ttt_d8TPo-eVY0W9k292F2LxxSBLE85CMh19yfa_Zp9k0bsoH8bDHkEIE5dexskBhESp9i2wOlBqN3bPtRvaGGwxR5TwWFri_8QMy83ysaLeU8a-kfPnKtiCrMrRdMf8j4GO6NENwDJ9omlXfazXpdh4yptltyv1U3Ho7dlRp-ioGtG9sLCk_JNNR9r51Ly5tyTLbRtAlB48-Gzv9x06iiJBKGZIG95H2oYSsRROo34TN3I42uzUHwskuivem1eI8C41Q0JybHb0_-mNQ
Header:  traceidb9dd7183-a0e1-4543-b96e-cb9db484f090
Header:  authorizationBearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImRlZmF1bHQifQ.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.DzgajPezQeJEW0g1qSZdBc8VR8OgQNZ1uVgNYs3iCABYYOThlDbqt5vK6TvcNkOzqnA8kxzG4z8iD0EDBTnbP34-ZFmQpIVDjpYaMsuewrTza9o7HVlPMyRDtpUthtr2HWzW_m72sGy2ylugV35OdONGAtHzYjEXpCqEtwc3_zGZSp79rkHWYfffHEvUzmKmj3ysEoQXr9593EbMMk45Z-qrxydBwKDAibsICDLDkgBRPJ0uiOr8osVQCgrEoLq8xRKCn3U3_vXMqjq8fmA_QabGrUA1TDowFjmjIjNQy-5l0atwkBYtu7vVsyD2dvbLWQVQdjyMcPTL4NdTKEg8aA
Header:  forwardedproto=http;host="localhost:8090";for="[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:51180"
Header:  x-forwarded-for0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
Header:  x-forwarded-protohttp
Header:  x-forwarded-port8090
Header:  x-forwarded-hostlocalhost:8090
Header:  hostlocalhost:8080
Header:  content-length0```
we can see that the headers are duplicate

i tried to modify the logic of the filter few times but i think maybe im using wrong the exchange.mutate()
````